# Optimised string insert algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, jruby

There is a small part of our software that inserts a string before and after a certain matched string on a huge chunk of code (average length 900000 characters).

Example:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Replaced with

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the `<span class="class1 class2">printing</span>` and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has `<span class="class1 class2 class3">been</span>` the industry's standard dummy text `<span class="class1">ever since the 1500s</span>`, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

---

Ok, so far so good. We could just search and replace, but the contents are somewhat semantical relative so `printing` in that case was replaced, but might not be in some other place of the text.
What we did was index where we wanted to replace the text, so for every replacement we get a starting position and an end position.

Current code:

```
new_val = huge_string_goes_here
entities.each { |entity|
    add_before = "<span class=\"#{entity.getStuff}\">"
    add_after = '</span>'

    new_val.insert(entity.getStart+increment, add_before)
    increment = increment+add_before.length
    new_val.insert(entity.getEnd+increment, add_after)
    increment = increment+add_after.length
}
```

Analysing a 900000 character long string is taking around 15-20 seconds.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we could optimize it?

Thank you

Comment: This should probably be on the http://codereview.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: If you are using Mac OS or Linux take a look at using `sed`. That is designed for this task and is very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing a [C extension module for Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html) which could find the match indices for you - this sort of operation should be much faster natively than with interpreted code.  Once you've got the indices you could use Ruby to insert the before/after text, or if the performance still needs a boost then consider doing it all in C.

Note that, as with any optimization, the critical thing is to make sure your "optimization" actually improves upon the non-optimized code.  Write a benchmark for some sample cases and keep track of the amount of time it takes the pure Ruby code, then run the same benchmark using your native extension and see if the performance is in fact better.

Comment: This presentation really helped me with C extensions: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/NFJS/RubyCExtensions.pdf Also looking through Ruby's core string method's is rather educational.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go to a lower-level language to get it done, perhaps it would be useful to change your thinking so that you scan through the source string once and write out a new one (if this could be pre-allocated,all the better), because that would remove the need to move all the ~900000-N characters behind the insertion point N.

<s>There are also special representations one can move into to make these sorts of operations very fast (such as [ropes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29)), but you shouldn't need something like that for this scenario.</s>

EDIT: Many old data-structures (and new ones too for that matter) that have good big-Os are slow in practice because of giant constant factors that have been ignored and/or they don't account for modern architecture (e.g caches, compute vs retrieve). Ropes seem way too pointer-intensive to be fast in practice, and you'd do much better with something like a [gap buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) for general buffer edits.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [foma](http://code.google.com/p/foma/) for that kind of task, but I'm not sure how well you can integrate the semantics. It's different from imperative thinking, but that case should be fairly easy, once you know the idea. Foma is the opensource implementation of [xfst](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis639/docs/xfst.html), so you can use their resources.